# C# DateTime conversion from Sting dd/MM/yyyy to DateTime MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I am trying to convert string which is in dd/MM/yyyy format and comes from calendar control.I am trying to convert in in MM/dd/yyyy format.

```
 string mydate = "dd/MM/yyyy";
 DateTime myConvertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate ,"MM/dd/yyyy" , CultureInfo.InverientCulture);
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you wanting to convert it to a `DateTime` (which does not have a 'format') or are you wanting to output a string of the `DateTime` in that format?

Comment: @Gailad actually it is in 13/02/1990

Comment: If it's coming from a calendar control, why are you fiddling around with *strings* at all? You should just be working with `DateTime` types throughout your code. Which as Stephen's pointed out, don't [*have* a format](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,130)

Comment: Set correct culture to your application and a datepicker control. This way all the date formats will be consistent

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
DateTime myConvertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate ,"dd/MM/yyyy" , CultureInfo.InverientCulture);
```

DateTime itself doesn't store data in any format, so the format you supply to parse exact is the format of the input string.  The format of a date is only seen when you convert it back to a string, for output in some way.  You could output the date in the format "MM/dd/yyyy" you want by using

```
myConvertedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

to convert the date to a string in the format you want.

Comment: This is effectively right, though as pointed out by Damien_The_Unbeliever, if the date is coming from a calendar control it will already be of type DateTime, so you won't need to use ParseExact, just the ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").

Comment: I used it but it still showing me same date `mydate = 19/07/2002`  still showing `19/07/2002`

Comment: @parish Did you do myDate = myConvertedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); and then look at the value of myDate afterwards?

Comment: @C.Knight Yes i did same thing and then checked.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is declare the string in the correct format.

```
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    string a = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string to DateTime with the original format of the string (ie. **"dd/MM/yyyy"**)
the following test will pass:

```
    string mydate = "13/05/2016";
    DateTime myConvertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

To parse the date to another format just use:
`myConvertedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: OP is the person who asked the question. If you're going to give examples like this you need to explain why you've done that and how the OP can apply it to their code. At no point did you state this is purely an example of how to use ParseExact. This might lead the OP to think they can just copy your code (bad idea, but does happen) and it will work for them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this,

```
yourDateTime.Value.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```